# Need a data set with players statistics like tackles, passes etc

Tags: r

I am searching online for a football data set which would have information on attributes of players like the players' number of tackles, passes, interception etc. My motive is to download this data set and apply clustering technique to it in R, but i can't seem to find any. Could any one please suggest the links to find the desired data set.  Thanking in anticipation.

Comment: This question would be better asked on [Open Data](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/)   Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can visit whoscored.com website and look for player statistics. I think you will get what you need.

Comment: Thanks, I got exactly what i was looking for.